# Juce vst synth: cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, audio, effect, vst, juce

I've generated source and project files for simple vst synth in Introjucer. The code compiles with one weird error:
error C2259: 'SimpleSynthAudioProcessor' : cannot instantiate abstract class

The compiler thinks that SimpleSynthAudioProcessor is an abstract class but it isn't!

This is my header file for that class: http://pastebin.com/Ge2sHAWq

And this is the header file for the base class of class above: http://pastebin.com/UKC7h5P5

I wasn't coding in C++ for a long time, but anyway I don't see any problem in this code.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't implemented `virtual bool silenceInProducesSilenceOut() const = 0;`

Comment: Do I need to implement every virtual function that's in the base class?

Comment: @PiotrJoniec, No, only the pure virtual ones marked as `= 0`. They're the ones that make the base class abstract.